# How to handle event Firebase when the app killed on Xamarin iOS or handle the event when The user press button clear notification?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm developing a chat application on `iOS` with `Xamarin Forms`.

I use `Firebase` for pushing notification (message chat) to the user.

I'm having a problem with `Firebase`. How to handle event `Firebase` when the app killed on `Xamarin iOS`?

**With my case**: When person A sends a message to person B. Person B saw the message on `lock screen`

[image: Lock_Screen]

But Person B doesn't want to see the message, He clear notification at `lock screen`

[image: clear message]

Person B didn't click (tap) the message to open the app, so I can't save the message to LocalDB of the app.

I thought of another solution. This is handled the event when The user press button clear notification. Can it be done on iOS?

**Summary**:

**1.** How to handle event `Firebase` when the app killed on `Xamarin iOS`?

**OR**

**2.** How to handle the event when The user press button clear notification?

Comment: Hi, as far as I know, to implement the push of chat messages, when the application is closed, the message push is only a function to assist the user to view, regardless of whether the user views or not, it will not affect the message push in the application. So, you need to distinguish between in-app and out-of-app push. What Firebase does is push outside the app, which is implemented through APNs. For in-app push, you can refer to the AMQP protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to some of my own researchs, firebase or even Onesignal don't fire in-app events when it's killed, you'll have to do some workaround this without firebase events, as you can see in this [post](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) there's only background and alive events